# Bootstrap affixed navbar--- width exceeds container and body EDITED

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

ORIGINAL POST

I'm having troubles with an affixed navbar.
When I scroll, my navbar increase its width, and it exceeds container and body width. Actually it runs out of the screen

this is my HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="encabezado row">
      <img class="img-responsive encabezado-pict" src="img/header.jpg">
    </div>

    <!-- ===================================== -->
    <!-- ============ NAV BAR ================ -->
    <!-- ===================================== -->
      <nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="222">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="dropdown" class="dropdown"><a href="3" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Nosotros <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Misión, Visión y Objetivos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Origen Bicéfalo</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" class="dropdown" class="dropdown" class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Normatividad <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Ley de profesiones</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reglamento a la Ley de profesiones</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Estatutos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Código de Ética</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Servicios <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Afiliación</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bolsa de empleo</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" class="dropdown" class="dropdown" class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Académicos <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Certificación</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Café Técnico</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Congresos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Convenios</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Estudiantiles <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Servicio Social y Prácticas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Conlami Universitario</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>   
  </div>
</header>
```

And this my CSS

```
    .affix {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
```

I tryed to give a static width but that's not responsive.

I thanks so much.

EDITED

I had found that the problem is this

```
<div class="container">
```

right after

```
<header>
```

I use that container to give a boxed look to my web header, otherwise it takes a stretched look.

I noticed that when I remove taht container, my fixed navbar with affix fits screen perfectly (1391px).

But when the container is there, fixed navbar takes exactly the same width (1391px),so navbar runs out of screen.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you write more descriptive of the problem can give you the full answer. But can you try `width:100%` instead `left:0; right:0;`... GL.

Comment: Actually I have `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `container-fluid` to `container` i hope it will OK.

Comment: I think it has to be fluid to work fine. I tryed it didnt work.